# Controller function call twice in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I click the save button to save my controller function is firing twice.  What is the problem in my code I don't know. Please help me.

Here is my button click to call ajax and save values.

```
<button id="btnSave" type="submit" title="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getPage('@(Url.Action("Save", "Carriers"))')">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Save
</button>
```

Here is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: page,
    data: $("#frmEdit").serialize(),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (html) {
        $('#CarrierList').empty();
        $('#CarrierList').append($.parseHTML(html));
    },
    error: function () {
        var error = "Error occured during loading Carrier items...";
        $('#errorMessage').empty();
        $('#errorMessage').append(error);
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#loaderImg').modal('hide');
    }
});
}
```

Here is my controller  method

```
public override ActionResult Save(CarrierDTO carrierDTO)
{
    string[] ErrorMessageArray = new string[4];
    int errorIndex = 0;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MessageCollection messages = new MessageCollection();
        carrierDTO.Save(ref messages);
        if (messages.IsErrorOccured() || messages.IsExceptionOccured())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", messages[0].Text);
            return View("Edit", carrierDTO);
        }
        return View("Edit", carrierDTO);
    }
```

Comment: Your button is `type="submit"` but your not cancelling the default submit action. Use `type="button"` or add `return false;` at the end of the script.

Comment: Is your HTML inside any form?

Comment: @StephenMuecke bro if i using return false end if the script its not working.. just change the type its working.

Comment: Then you did not add it in the right place. But using `type="button" is better anyway.

Comment: Your button is likely inside a `Html.beginform` and combined with your `type="submit"` is firing the same action twice both through the form action and the on click event. Just change to `type="button"`

Comment: yes tomuke thumbs up bro

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'preventDefault()'.

> If the prevent default method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

In your case, the prevent default will stop submitting the form(the default action of the submit button), and use the ajax snippet to do so instead.

**JQ:**

```
  $(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: page,
            data: $("#frmEdit").serialize(),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $('#CarrierList').empty();
                $('#CarrierList').append($.parseHTML(html));
            },
            error: function () {
                var error = "Error occured during loading Carrier items...";
                $('#errorMessage').empty();
                $('#errorMessage').append(error);
                $('#errorModal').modal('show');
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loaderImg').modal('hide');
            }
        });
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

- Use `type="button"` in your button control

  `<button id="btnSave" type="button" title="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getPage('@(Url.Action("Save", "Carriers"))')">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Save
  </button>`
- or remove `onclick="getPage('@(Url.Action("Save", "Carriers"))')`, because the submit button take a post *action* in default .

  `<button id="btnSave" type="submit" title="Save" class="btn btn-success" ">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Save
  </button>`

Answer (score 0):

In you App_Start folder open the BudleConfig.cs file and do few changes:
First take a look to this line (this is an original VS generated content).

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Note that '...validate*' pattern will load five scripts from your Scripts folder (this is true for my case):

```
~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

As you can see, you are loading the unobtrusive.js twice (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js). So, make your own code something like this to exclude, say full version js:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

or make some mechanism to load full or min versions per your desire.